# Do HTTP responses have HTTP methods?

Tags: html, http, post, httpresponse, http-method

I am learning HTTP and I have a basic question:

> Do HTTP responses have HTTP methods like in the HTTP requests (GET,
> POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)?

If so, I have another question:

> Does the HTTP method of an HTTP response always is POST to allow
> having a body in HTML, SOAP or JSON?

Comment: First question, no it doens't have the methods in the HTTP packet header. Second, It doesn't use any of those methods to send you the response data (this might helps: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)